# how to deploy a short python script on a single computer?

Tags: python, deployment

the idea is for my dad to very simply enter a word (a medicine name : input) and get a few sentences out depending on the medicine name ( common prescribing scenarios: output) , without having to deal with anything technical at all. i have ONLY HEARD about docker etc. though i dont know how they function, but im after the simplest way to do this as im a complete beginner.

Comment: I believe the objectively correct answer is to write a small Graphical User Interface with `tkinter` and create an executable file with `py2exe`.

Comment: @timgeb is on the ball here. pyinstaller is another good option for making it easy for the recipient.

Comment: well, you could copy the file to his desktop and all he'd have to do is double click